# Obfuscating strings.xml file in android code

Tags: android, apk, proguard, obfuscation

I would like to prevent anyone decompiling my .apk file from viewing some of the strings in the strings.xml file.

Will obfuscating my code using ProGuard obfuscate or hide the strings.xml file and prevent people from seeing the original strings.

Comment: You cannot prevent anyone from viewing anything in your app. Obfuscating only makes it harder - but not by much. It is only a really small hurdle for anyone who knows what they are doing or has enough motivation to do it anyway. If you want to hide some information in your app and prevent anyone from accessing it unless by using your app then you are on the wrong path. Hiding anything in your client code is impossible.

Comment: What you can do is: obfuscate the strings yourself before putting them in the strings.xml file. Then de-obfuscate them in code.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein that does not work either. Doing something like this just makes your code more complicated for basically no added benefit. Never **ever** obfuscate code yourself, that is just a terrible idea.

Comment: Well, how can I tell you, @XaverKapeller... It works, for me!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am not doubting that it works. I am just saying that implementing something like this has no point whatsoever.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein let me answer your question with another question: what benefit do you get from obfuscating strings yourself, putting them that way in the strings.xml and then manually deobfuscating them in code?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Very simple: a casual observer won't be able to understand what's written in the strings.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein A casual observer that just happens to decompile or extract your app? And all that to protect strings that are basically just the same text the user sees when opening your app anyway? Anyone who knows what they are doing and spends 5 minutes looking at your app can find the deobfuscating code in your app and run it for himself. And of course this all assumes that anyone would ever be interested in the contents of strings.xml - which are just translations - anyway and not other parts of the app.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein And the price you have to pay for all that is additional code complexity and no easy way to edit or view the strings.xml yourself? I really don't understand anything about this. If you want your strings to be obfuscated then use of of the many tools that do it for you. Never do it yourself. Does not make any sense.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes, but. If you are so much concerned (I was at those times and the OP still is at the moment) with piracy, it's a way to get a (false) feeling of enhanced protection. That said, I'm no longer worrying about that.

Answer (score 2):

Proguard will not obfuscate strings.  It basically performs minimization on the java.  If you want strings to be obfuscated several options are available.  Here are a couple

Stringer: https://jfxstore.com/stringer/

DexGuard: https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard